# Running AppleScripts through the ScriptMonitor.app Utility

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, system-calls

When AppleScripts are run through the system-wide Script Menu, their progress is displayed in the menu bar using the ScriptMonitor applet (located in `/System/Library/CoreServices/ScriptMonitor.app`, introduced in OS X Yosemite).  This allows you to stay aware of running scripts, monitor progress, and easily stop running scripts.

[image: ScriptMonitor Icon]

Is it possible to run AppleScripts through the ScriptMonitor from outside the Script Menu, for example from Terminal or from system calls from other applications?

I have tried various permutations of the following commands, all without success:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/ScriptMonitor.app/Contents/MacOS/ScriptMonitor /PATH/TO/SCRIPT
```

or

```
open -a /System/Library/CoreServices/ScriptMonitor.app --args /PATH/TO/SCRIPT
```

The reason this would be useful is that there are many helper applications that run AppleScripts in response to events, but tend not to be very good at notifying the user about their success or failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it turns out this can be done using *NSUserScriptTask* from the Cocoa frameworks, either as part of a compiled command-line application or through AppleScript/Objective-C (ASObjC).

This solution allows AppleScripts, Automator workflows, and shell scripts to be run from the System ScriptMonitor.app utility.

#### ASObjC Solution

This handler will run natively on OS X 10.10 Yosemite and later. It takes a single parameter, a string containing the POSIX-style (slash-delimited) path to the script. The script is executed immediately in the background, and no result is returned.

```
use framework "Foundation"

to runInScriptMonitor(script_path)

    set {script_task, url_error} to current application's NSUserScriptTask's alloc()'s initWithURL:(script_path as POSIX file) |error|:(reference)
    if url_error is not missing value then error (url_error's localizedDescription as string) number (url_error's code as integer)
    script_task's executeWithCompletionHandler:(missing value)

    # The following delay was increased due to a system hang on Mojave after installation of Security Update 2020-004 (previously, the delay was 0.05).
    delay 10 -- Necessary to allow NSUserScriptTask to be dispatched before execution terminates.

    return

end runInScriptMonitor
```

It is called as follows: `runInScriptMonitor("/PATH/TO/FILE")`

This allows you to run scripts in ScriptMonitor from within AppleScript. If the call is placed in a wrapper AppleScript, the wrapper script can then be called from the command line using `osascript`.

#### Compiled Objective-C Solution

Follow these instructions to create a command-line program that takes the script path as input and runs the script using ScriptMonitor. You **must** have the *Xcode Command Line Tools* (or the full *Xcode*) installed in order to compile the code.

1. Save the following code as `osascriptmonitor.m` in the Desktop folder:

   ```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
        if (argc < 2) {
            printf("usage: osascriptmonitor /path/to/script\n");

        } else {
            NSString *script_path = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];
            NSUserScriptTask *script_task = [[NSUserScriptTask alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:script_path] error:nil];
            [script_task executeWithCompletionHandler:nil];
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:60.0f];
        }

        return 0;
    }
   ```
2. Compile the program by running the following commands from Terminal:

   ```
    cd ~/Desktop
    gcc -framework Foundation osascriptmonitor.m -o osascriptmonitor
   ```
3. You will now have an executable file named `osascriptmonitor` on your Desktop. You can run that program from Terminal, passing the path of the script that you want to run in ScriptMonitor.

Example (replace `/PATH/TO/SCRIPT` with the path of the script you want to run):

```
    ~/Desktop/osascriptmonitor "/PATH/TO/SCRIPT"
```

If you then move the executable file to `/usr/local/bin`, you can run the program without having to specify its entire path.

```
    osascriptmonitor "/PATH/TO/SCRIPT"
```

---

**Edit Jan 3, 2020:**

#### Direct Solution

By happy accident, I stumbled across an undocumented option for `osascript` that makes the above largely unnecessary for AppleScripts: the `-P` switch.

Usage:  `osascript -P "/PATH/TO/SCRIPT"`

On its own, this will make the script appear in the menu *only if Script Monitor is already running*. Script Monitor can be launched ahead of time (or while the script is running) and will quit automatically once all scripts have finished.

The best way to launch Script Monitor is using the -g option:

```
open -g /System/Library/CoreServices/ScriptMonitor.app
```

Using this method, it is possible to easily pass arguments to the script in addition to having it appear in Script Monitor.

Comment: This was very helpful. Is there any way you know of to run these scripts through ScriptMonitor while also passing paramters / arguments to them?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any easy way to pass arguments to NSUserScriptTask...  You could generate a temporary trampoline script that would execute the primary script with arguments, and pass the trampoline script path to the above handler.
The trampoline script would have to handle different types of primary scripts (e.g. AppleScript, shell, etc.) manually, which NSUserScriptTask normally handles transparently.

Comment: Mojave Security Update 2020-004 causes the system to lock up if the program exits too quickly after running a script requiring Accessibility permission; I've increased the sleep/delay above to reflect this.