# Stop a running AppleScript in such a way that calls its error handler

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, system-calls

I run automation scripts using ssh. The scripts are written in AppleScript. I would like to be able to stop a script in such a way that it's error handler is called rather than just stopping dead.

Using the following AppleScript as an example:

```
on run

    try
        repeat with i from 1 to 1000
            delay 1
        end repeat

    on error
        beep 1
    end try

end run
```

I save the script to my home folder as test.applescript

I then run it from the terminal:

```
osascript ~/test.applescript
```

Is there anyway to stop the script from the command line in such a way that you hear the beep? using `kill -s SIGHUP` stops the script but I do not hear a beep. I've tried all the signals to no avail.

The closest I've gotten is by using the following:

`osacriptmonitor ~/test.applescript` and then using the gear menu to cancel. By doing that I hear the beep. (please see [Running AppleScripts through the ScriptMonitor.app Utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081057) for more information on osascriptmonitor).

It's also important to note that when I use `osacriptmonitor` instead `osascript`, I get the following from `ps -ax | grep osascript`:

`/usr/bin/osascript -T 4984 -P /Users/david/test.applescript`

Does anyone know what `-T` and `-P` are used for? I have been unable to find any reference to those options.

Answer (score 1):

Applescript runs from beginning to the end. If you kill it the whole script is removed.

If you want to have a more controllable ending you need to include another routine in your loop. E.g. check something outside the script every tenth loop. Then you only need to change that outside value to trigger something else inside your script.

Comment: Reasonable idea. In `bash` scripts I have checked regularly for the existence of a file called `/PAUSE` and then users can pause them by doing `touch /PAUSE`.